# Does sharing SID by processes *always* imply their shared PGID?

Tags: linux, session

If not, then when does it diverge?

(I couldn't make them diverge.)

And what other traits do SID-sharing processes **always** share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions contain process groups which contain processes.

Those were created mostly for terminal job control. A session is typically associated to a login session in a terminal, or the whole shell session in a terminal emulator.

When you login or start `xterm`, a new process is created that starts a new session (which automatically starts a new process group) and that process (which is now both a session leader and process group leader) executes your login shell. By opening the terminal device without O_NOCTTY, that process also associates that terminal device to the session (and becomes the *controlling process* of that terminal). That terminal device becomes the *controlling terminal* of all the processes in that session.

That shell then runs jobs each in their own process group (by forking a process that starts a new process group and may end up forking several other processes in that group (for instance for pipelines like `cmd1 | cmd2`)) and does special `ioctl()s` to the terminal device to tell it which of those jobs is in foreground (so they can do I/O to the terminal and receive the SIGINT upon CTRL-C for instance).

So, yes, you typically have several process groups per session.

For instance in an interactive shell:

```
$ sleep 1 | sh -c 'sleep 2; :' & ps -j
[1] 2902 2903
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
 2902  2902  4648 pts/23   00:00:00 sleep
 2903  2902  4648 pts/23   00:00:00 sh
 2904  2904  4648 pts/23   00:00:00 ps
 2905  2902  4648 pts/23   00:00:00 sleep
 4648  4648  4648 pts/23   00:00:00 zsh
```

3 processe groups, one in foreground (`ps`), one in background with 3 processes (`sleep`, `sleep`, `sh`) and my interactive shell.

All processes of a process group are necessarily in the same session as creating a new session (which you can't do if you're a process group leader) automatically creates a new process group.

I recommend reading

```
info libc 'Job Control'
```

on a GNU system for more information.

Comment: "you typically have several process groups per session"  -- What things are invariant in a session then? What traits/attributes/anything will always be shared by processes with a common SID?

Comment: @dziadek1990. The controlling terminal if any. Sessions are also used for automatic signal delivery in some circumstancies.